# Getting very high values in linear regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

I am trying to make a simple MLP to predict values of a pixel of an image - [original blog](http://evolvingstuff.blogspot.in/2012/12/generating-mona-lisa-pixel-by-pixel.html) .
Here's my earlier attempt using Keras in python - [link](https://github.com/goelakash/MonaNet/blob/master/MonaNet.py)

I've tried to do the same in tensorflow, but I am getting very large output values (~10^12) when they should be less than 1.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from random import shuffle
import tensorflow as tf

'''
Image preprocessing
'''
image_file = cv2.imread("Mona Lisa.jpg")

h = image_file.shape[0]
w = image_file.shape[1]

preX = []
preY = []

for i in xrange(h):
    for j in xrange(w):
        preX.append([i,j])
        preY.append(image_file[i,j,:].astype('float32')/255.0)

print preX[:5], preY[:5]
zipped = [i for i in zip(preX,preY)]
shuffle(zipped)

X_train = np.array([i for (i,j) in zipped]).astype('float32')
Y_train = np.array([j for (i,j) in zipped]).astype('float32')

print X_train[:10], Y_train[:10]

'''
Tensorflow code
'''

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,2])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,3])



'''
Layers
'''

w1 = weight_variable([2,300])
b1 = bias_variable([300])
L1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X_train,w1)+b1)

w2 = weight_variable([300,3])
b2 = bias_variable([3])
y_model = tf.matmul(L1,w2)+b2


'''
Training
'''

# criterion
MSE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(y,y_model)))

# trainer
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.01).minimize(MSE)

nb_epochs = 10

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)
cost = 0

for i in range(nb_epochs):
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict ={x: X_train, y: Y_train})
    cost += sess.run(MSE, feed_dict ={x: X_train, y: Y_train})

cost /= nb_epochs
print cost


'''
Prediction
'''

pred = sess.run(y_model,feed_dict = {x:X_train})*255.0
print pred[:10]

output_image = []
index = 0

h = image_file.shape[0]
w = image_file.shape[1]

for i in xrange(h):
    row = []

    for j in xrange(w):
        row.append(pred[index])
        index += 1

    row = np.array(row)
    output_image.append(row)

output_image = np.array(output_image)
output_image = output_image.astype('uint8')
cv2.imwrite('out_mona_300x3_tf.png',output_image)
```

Comment: The values oscillate from 10^12 to 10^22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think that instead of running the train_op and then the MSE
you can run both ops in a list and reduce your computational cost significantly.

```
for i in range(nb_epochs):
cost += sess.run([MSE, train_op], feed_dict ={x: X_train, y: Y_train})
```

Secondly, I suggest always writing out your cost function so you can see what is going on during the training phase. Either manually print it out or use tensorboard to log your cost and plot it (you can find examples on the official tf page). 
You can also monitor your weights to see that they aren't blowing up.

A few things you can try: 
Reduce learning rate, add regularization to weights.
Check that your training set (pixels) really consist of the values that 
you expect them to.

Comment: Yes, training set is correct (I have a print statement in the image preprocessing step). I can see that the cost increases from 10^9 to 10^21 with each iteration. But I can't seem to find whats wrong. My error function looks okay to me.

Comment: So did you try decreasing learning rate and/or decreasing your std on the random initialization of the weights?

Comment: Yes, reducing std to   `0.01` gets valid output now. But the network  doesn't learn the input (still appears as random noise). Is this tweaking necessary in general?

Comment: Here's the output of training with 3 hidden layers (300 each) for 200 iterations - (http://i.imgur.com/g0C3pRk.png). Compare that with the output of a similar network in Keras -  http://i.imgur.com/1hjiZT8.png

Comment: This tweaking is usually essential when doing this kind of stuff.  I'm not sure why you are getting random noise. There could be many reasons. Print out your cost every iteration so you can see what is happening. Without it you are pretty much in the blind.

Answer (score 0):

You give the input layer weights and the output layer weights the same names `w` and `b`, so it seems something goes wrong in the gradient-descent procedure. Actually I'm surprised tensorflow doesn't issue an error or at leas a warning (or am I missing something?)

Comment: No, I tried giving different names to the  variables. Doesn't help. I'll edit my code anyway.